# Oracle - select most voted items by distinct users

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle tables like below:

```
User - UserId,
Item - ItemId,
UserVote - UserVoteId, UserId, ItemId.
```

Now a user can vote multiple times. I am having a hard time with this query: Get item(s) most voted **uniquely** - meaning multiple votes from the same person count only as one.

If it was SQL Server, I might have created temp table and all, but I do not know how to handle in Oracle. I'm also having a hard time thinking how to handle tie, meaning if two items both have 18 "unique" votes. I would want both items in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ItemID,
       VoteCount
from
  (
    select ItemID,
           count(distinct UserId) as VoteCount,
           rank() over(order by count(distinct UserId) desc) as rn
    from UserVote
    group by ItemID
  ) U
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.*,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY votes DESC) AS dr
        FROM    (
                SELECT  itemId, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS votes
                FROM    userVote
                GROUP BY
                        itemId
                ) q
        )
WHERE   dr = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) AS votes,
        item.ItemId
    FROM
        UserVote
    GROUP BY
        item.ItemId
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    item
    LEFT JOIN CTE
        CTE.ItemId=item.ItemId
ORDER BY
    votes DESC;
```

This will `COUNT` the users that has voted distinct. So you will have unique users per item id. I don't know what output you want so I ordered so that the item with the most votes are first. If you want just a top 10 or something you can quite easy add it to the select.

Comment: does oracle support CTE syntax?

Comment: yes.. http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10947/usage-of-cte-sql-server-vs-oracle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT "ItemId", COUNT(*) AS "VoteCount"
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "ItemId", "UserID"
          FROM "UserVote") a
  GROUP BY "ItemId"
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The following ANSI query returns the most voted Items, not considering multiple votes by the same user (you will have to limit the returned rows into your application):

```
SELECT ItemId, COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) AS "votes"
FROM UserVote
GROUP BY ItemId
ORDER BY "votes" DESC;
```

If you really need to limit the number of rows into the query, you can do it by using Oracle SQL dialect:

```
SELECT ItemId, votes
FROM (
  SELECT ItemId, COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) AS "votes"
  FROM UserVote
  GROUP BY ItemId
  ORDER BY "votes" DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= :n; -- :n is a placeholder for the number of rows to return
```